# Get scrollbar width and minus from div width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code where the its getting the scroll width and minus it from the div width and it works fine, but the problem is its not working within window.resize, how do I get it working in window.resize?

Here is the JS code

```
//get scrollbar width
function getScrollBarWidth () {
  var inner = document.createElement('p');
  inner.style.width = "100%";
  inner.style.height = "200px";
  var outer = document.createElement('div');
  outer.style.position = "absolute";
  outer.style.top = "0px";
  outer.style.left = "0px";
  outer.style.visibility = "hidden";
  outer.style.width = "200px";
  outer.style.height = "150px";
  outer.style.overflow = "hidden";
  outer.appendChild (inner);
  document.body.appendChild (outer);
  var w1 = inner.offsetWidth;
  outer.style.overflow = 'scroll';
  var w2 = inner.offsetWidth;
  if (w1 == w2) w2 = outer.clientWidth;
  document.body.removeChild (outer);
  return (w1 - w2);
 };
//header width minus scrollbar width
$("header").width($("header").width() - getScrollBarWidth() + "px");
```

Comment: add a function to invoke `getScrollBarWidth` function while window resize

Comment: @azad can you suggest a example please?

Comment: I think Luis Gar answered correctly.

Comment: that I have already tried but its not working

Answer (score 0):

I think the better solution is https://api.jquery.com/resize/

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
$("header").width($("header").width() - getScrollBarWidth() + "px");
});
```

Edited as the comment: Try a timeOut

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
setTimeout(funtion(){$("header").width($("header").width() - getScrollBarWidth() + "px");},300)
});
```

Comment: this is what I have already tried, if you alert the getScrollbarWidth return 0

Comment: what it returns when not resizing the window?

Comment: You can add a timeOut for waiting the window is resized. Try.

Comment: $( window ).resize(function() {
setTimeout(function(){$("header").width($("header").width() - getScrollBarWidth() + "px");}, 300);
});

Comment: @azad its returning zero in alert when resizing

Answer (score 0):

put this declaration anywhere in your script file that contains the "getScrollBarWidth" function.

```
onresize = getScrollBarWidth;
```

Comment: not working, my requirement is get the width of div - scroll width on resize

Comment: @SanjeevK, isn't "the function you yourself named as "getScrollBarWidth", the one that does it for you! 
Why name it that way? If not than you need to wrap a function for the code that does it e.g.: `$("header").width($("header").width() - getScrollBarWidth() + "px");`  and assing it to the `onresize` event. And it will.

Comment: Yes function is same and even I tried with this but it doesnt work onresize = $("header").width($("header").width() - getScrollBarWidth() + "px");